# Can't resize some icons

Tags: nautilus, icons

I upgraded to 12.10 yesterday and I am having a problem. Icons of my files are shown as the icon image's original size.

I tried to resize the icons but it did not work! But the normal size icons seems to be alright.
[image: Icon Problem]

- `Tasks` icon is shrunk by me (I can do this).
- `Archive` icon is of original size.
- `Deliverables` icon is enlarged (I can do this too).
- `Eclipse` icon is the problem. The image used for this one is `256x256`. The icon is shown as that size. I cannot resize it to be smaller (or larger).

I am not sure if its important, I used `Upgrade` option from a bootable USB to install 12.10.

Comment: Might be related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/990042).

Comment: here's a workaround that worked for me: http://askubuntu.com/a/786389/538840

Answer (score 1):

Try: Right click on the icon and selection "Original Size", then attempt to resize again.

Otherwise, move aside the dconf/gconf settings directories and restart nautilus (log off) and try again.

Everything checks out here, resizing both .desktop files and normal files.

Comment: can anyone tell me which dconf/gconf dirs to move away? those in `etc/*`?

Comment: Not the ones in /etc, it's in your home folder. You must show hidden files and then move folders .gnome .gtk .config/gnome etc etc. You can move as many as you like somewhere