# Cannot resize Chome app icon on Unity desktop

Tags: unity, 16.04, google-chrome, icons

When I add a [Chrome app](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3060053) to the Unity desktop, the Icon is huge and I cannot resize it:

i.e. when I right-click on the Icon and select `Resize Icon...`, I see the resize-handles, but dragging will not change the size. Note: resizing works for all other icons on the Desktop.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

here's the easiest way, I've found to fix this problem:

- Find the `.desktop` file of the chrome-app: e.g.
  `~/Desktop/chrome-lbfehkoinhhcknnbdgnnmjhiladcgbol-Default.desktop`
- the `Icon` is set to something like this
  `Icon=chrome-lbfehkoinhhcknnbdgnnmjhiladcgbol-Default`
- I simply change this entry to include the full path and extension to the icon file:
  `Icon=/home/USER/.local/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/chrome-lbfehkoinhhcknnbdgnnmjhiladcgbol-Default.png`
  You must replace USER in with your own user-name (note: `~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/chrome-lbfehkoinhhcknnbdgnnmjhiladcgbol-Default.png` does not work)
- save the changes and now the icon has the correct size and I can also resize it.

Note:

- I found out where the icon is stored via `gnome-desktop-item-edit`: e.g.
- `gnome-desktop-item-edit chrome-lbfehkoinhhcknnbdgnnmjhiladcgbol-Default.desktop`
- Then a small dialogue will appear - click the icon on the left and a file-chooser dialogue will open up.

Comment: You can replace `/home/USER` with `~` so that you can remove the note that says "note: you must replace USER in with your own user-name".

Comment: I've tried that, but this does not work.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting and surprising. Thanks for letting me know. Would you happen to know why it doesn't work?

Comment: I've also tried `~` first. Sorry, I don't know the reason.

Comment: `~` indeed wouldn't work, but `$HOME` would.

Comment: `$HOME`  also does not work.